# How to get the Document template url in Sharepoint designer workflows or jquery

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have multiple document templates attached to a content type for a document library.  Is there any way through designer workflows or jquery to get the document template url.

Below is the url  for configuring the document templates for a document library.

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/01/07/using-content-types-with-document-templates-when-using-quotnew-documentrdquo.aspx

Comment: Multiple templates attached to content type OR multiple content type attached to a document library?

Comment: Each template is attached to a content type. I.e if I have 3 content types which are in use for a document library. Each content type has a separate template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document template's `URL` can be found in the following end-point.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your Library Name')/ContentTypes?$select=DocumentTemplate,DocumentTemplateUrl
```

You have to make a GET request in the above `URL` using jQuery.

```
function getTemplateUrl(libraryName) {
    var url = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + libraryName + "')/ContentTypes?$select=DocumentTemplate,DocumentTemplateUrl"
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Response will be like following

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'63ff3aad-360b-4484-aade-283e603a975e')/ContentTypes('0x010100DA61ED65E37DE94084A585C06CB4F2D5')",
          "uri": "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'63ff3aad-360b-4484-aade-283e603a975e')/ContentTypes('0x010100DA61ED65E37DE94084A585C06CB4F2D5')",
          "type": "SP.ContentType"
        },
        "DocumentTemplate": "/Shared Documents/Forms/template.dotx",
        "DocumentTemplateUrl": "/Shared Documents/Forms/template.dotx"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'63ff3aad-360b-4484-aade-283e603a975e')/ContentTypes('0x010100009856EF229E504FBF311FF61AB0E7000003FD588DCA1E6E4AB5A28B8441C27671')",
          "uri": "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'63ff3aad-360b-4484-aade-283e603a975e')/ContentTypes('0x010100009856EF229E504FBF311FF61AB0E7000003FD588DCA1E6E4AB5A28B8441C27671')",
          "type": "SP.ContentType"
        },
        "DocumentTemplate": "Excel Template.xlsx",
        "DocumentTemplateUrl": "/Shared Documents/Forms/Excel Content Type/Excel Template.xlsx"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Awesome.... I will add it in my blog

Comment: Then share with me

Comment: but when I use this document url it updating the template. My scenario was to create a new  document in to the document library using this template url.. Any idea why it behaving like that

Comment: I did not get your scenario. Please explain more

Comment: once we copy paste the url in a browser it open up the template. Now when I add some content and save the template it is not saving in the document library. where as it is updating the document template. It should as a new document in the document library right?

Comment: Got your point but I did not work with this yet. try to find out

Comment: no problem , thanks for your solution i thought i was done .. if you find any solution let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30497/discussion-between-sandy143-and-atish-dipongkor).